# How to reference a parameter from a constructor in another class?

Tags: java, user-interface, button, constructor, jframe

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;


public class ProductButton extends JButton {

     private String productName;
     private double productPrice;

   /**
    Creates a button that will display an image of the product
    (assumed to be stored in a file starting with the specified
    name and ending with ".jpg"), the specified product name,
    and the specified price (formatted properly); the text is 
    displayed below the image and is centered.
    @param name The product name.
    @param price The selling price for this product.
   */

     public ProductButton (String name, double price) {

        productName = name;
        productPrice = price;

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(name + ".jpg");
        this.setIcon(icon);

        NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        this.setText(f.format(price)); 


        this.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        this.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.BOTTOM);
    }

    public String getName() { 
        return productName; 
    }

    public double getPrice() { 
        return productPrice; 
    }
}
```

Driver:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;



public class SnackShopFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{   
   private ProductButton coffeeButton, cocoaButton, donutButton, cookieButton, muffinButton, cupcakeButton;
   private JButton newCustomer;
   private JLabel totalPrintOut, totalPriceString;
   private double totalPrice;

    public SnackShopFrame(){
      JFrame window = new JFrame("Snack Shop Register");
      window.setSize(500,700);

      JPanel first = new JPanel();
      JLabel direction = new JLabel("Click on the products that the customer wishes to purchase:");
      first.add(direction);
      first.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      first.add(direction, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      JPanel second = new JPanel();
      second.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2,10,10));
      coffeeButton = new ProductButton("coffee", 3.75);
      coffeeButton.addActionListener(this);
      second.add(coffeeButton);

      cocoaButton = new ProductButton("cocoa", 2.25);
      cocoaButton.addActionListener(this);
      second.add(cocoaButton);

      donutButton = new ProductButton("donut",1.50);
      donutButton.addActionListener(this);
      second.add(donutButton);   

      cookieButton = new ProductButton("cookie", 1.25);   
      cookieButton.addActionListener(this);
      second.add(cookieButton);

      muffinButton = new ProductButton("muffin", 1.75);
      muffinButton.addActionListener(this);
      second.add(muffinButton);

      cupcakeButton = new ProductButton("cupcake", 1.50);
      cupcakeButton.addActionListener(this);
      second.add(cupcakeButton);

      JPanel third = new JPanel();
      totalPrintOut = new JLabel("");
      third.add(totalPrintOut);
      newCustomer = new JButton("Next Customer");
      newCustomer.addActionListener(this);
      third.add(newCustomer);

      Container contentPane = window.getContentPane();
      contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      contentPane.add(first, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      contentPane.add(second, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      contentPane.add(third, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      window.setVisible(true);
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        if(e.getSource() != newCustomer){
            if(e.getSource() == coffeeButton){
                totalPrice += 3.75;

            }
            if(e.getSource() == cocoaButton){
                totalPrice += 2.25;

            }
            if (e.getSource() == donutButton){
                totalPrice += 1.50;

            }
            if (e.getSource() == cookieButton){
                totalPrice += 1.25;

            }
            if (e.getSource() == muffinButton){
                totalPrice += 1.75;

            }
            if (e.getSource() == cupcakeButton){
                totalPrice += 1.50;
            }
        }

        if(e.getSource() == newCustomer ){
            totalPrice = 0; 
        }
        totalPriceString = new JLabel(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
        totalPrintOut.setText("Current total: $" + totalPrice);

    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        new SnackShopFrame().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

How do I get the values in my Driver class (in the if statements) to be formatted using the NumberFormat instance I made in the first class?

Also, when I run the GUI, I get two windows that open. One is blank and one is my actual program. How do I get the blank one to stop opening up?

Comment: I know this isn't what you asked - but instead of all your `if` statements, you could just write `totalPrice += e.getSource().getPrice();`

Comment: This would help me a lot if I could reference price. It is in my constructor in the first class, and I do not know how to refer to that parameter in my driver class. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: Hah, sorry, I made a mistake in my last comment.  I believe it should be `totalPrice += ((ProductButton) e.getSource()).getPrice();`.  Sorry to put you crook first time.

Comment: Yay! It worked! now I just need to format my numbers. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Well, yes, you're already using `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` in the buttons.  Can't you just use it in the driver class too?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. :(

Comment: OK, check my answer then.  I think it's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.  Definitely not the only way or the most efficient, but possibly the easiest to understand.  Instead of writing

```
totalPriceString = new JLabel(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
totalPrintOut.setText("Current total: $" + totalPrice);
```

just use exactly the same technique as you used for the product buttons.

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
totalPrintOut.setText("Current total: " + f.format(totalPrice));
```

Comment: It definitely works, but I am told to make use of the NumberFormat instance I made in the ProductButton class. Can you help me with that?

Comment: But you made six different `NumberFormat` instances in your `ProductButton` class.  If you want only one, you'll have to use a `static` variable in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:

In your product button class, declare the number formatter as a private member which is then initialised in the constructor. Then, make a getter method for it.

In your driver class, call your number formatter getter of the object in question to format your number.

Comment: My prof told us not to do so. She wants us to do it all in the constructor of ProductButton.java. We are not allowed to change anything else in the code.